# Paperclip - undefined method 'icon_file_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip, attachment

I've just installed the Paperclip and trying to attach an icon to my model.

```
has_attached_file :icon, 
                  :styles => { :normal => "100x100>", :format => 'png' },
                  :storage => :s3, 
                  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
                  :url => "/icon/:slug.:extension"
                  :path => "icon/:slug.:extension"
```

s3.yml contains my bucket name and two keys.

slug interpolation is defined in the config/initializers/paperclip.rb as

```
Paperclip.interpolates('slug') do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.cached_slug
end
```

When I call game.icon.url, I get this error:

```
undefined method `icon_file_name' for #<Game:0x4000f50>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running rails 3.0.4 and ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7 x64, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you create a migration for your Game model to add in the appropriate fields that Paperclip needs? From the [Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) on Github:

```
class AddAvatarColumnsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_name,    :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_content_type, :string
    add_column :users, :avatar_file_size,    :integer
    add_column :users, :avatar_updated_at,   :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_name
    remove_column :users, :avatar_content_type
    remove_column :users, :avatar_file_size
    remove_column :users, :avatar_updated_at
  end
end
```

After you've created that migration, you need to run the rake task to update your db: `rake db:migrate`

Comment: protip: you can get this by running the `paperclip` generator

Comment: Whoa, I didn't think it is necessary, since i'm using slug (which already exists in the table) for the filename

Comment: this is independent of where the data is eventually being stored. Paperclip uses the ActiveRecord model which is tied to a schema.

Comment: This is kinda sad. I really didn't want to duplicate the slug for several attachments. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply run - `rails generate paperclip game icon`

and it will generate the migration for you.

Answer (score 2):

I made the same mistake, forgot to add the database migrations.

Here is a great article on doing this
[even though it is on Heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3)

You can run the migrations like so

Create the migration file

```
rails g migration AddAvatarToUser
```

Then edit the file to the following

```
class AddAvatarToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :users, :avatar
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :users, :avatar
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but it was working when I ran it in the browser, yet some of my tests were failing.  You helped me realize that I had migrated my main development database, but I had failed to do a **rake db:migrate test**.  Once I did that - problem disappeared.